# Where image map is not supported?

Tags: html, image, compatibility

I am wondering if I create an html email with image map, where it can not be properly displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CampaignMonitor has a [handy chart showing email client compatibility](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3475/image-maps-in-html-email/) for image maps. In short, they work with a large number of email services but their use is discouraged for other reasons.