# HTML <map> tag not working with Outlook Email client

Tags: html, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to email a HTML based photograph with clickable links on it. I used the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Document Title </title>
<body>
<img src="online photohosting URL" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="outlet URL to this specific area of image" shape="rect" coords="280,348,145,213" />
    [...]
</map>
</body>
</title>
</head>
</html>
```

It works when I save it in HTML format and open in web browser but when I insert HTML file as text in Outlook, the recipient can only see the image but not the map. Are there any modifications to the code that need to be made ? Or are there any other  workarounds to this ?
Thank you

Comment: Typically email clients don't support full HTML elements, etc. Typically you should try and keep emails simple

Comment: The answer to this is, [Outlook doesn't support it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311471/where-image-map-is-not-supported)

Comment: You may have encountered some emails where you get an image with clickable links. If you know, can you please tell me how they are done ?

Comment: See Mario's answer

Answer (score 2):

Outlook has no support for this. You should keep html email as simple as possible.

However you can for example cut the image in portions so you can recombine all of them in the original image with the use of table html tags, then you can link the single portions to different links. This is fairly acceptable workaround for html image maps in emails.

Comment: Hi I did as you said but the final image appeared distorted. I used Photoshop's slicing tool to add links on specific location on the image. Uploaded the sliced sections on an image hosting website and used the hyperlinks in the <img src> tag. But the end results had white space in the linked region. Can this be solved ? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of your html? So I can see what's wrong.  (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: There is some confidential information in the image which I am not allowed to share. However this is the link to the screenshot http://s1381.photobucket.com/user/shrijanaryal123/media/paystub1_zpsa6gnzxua.png.html                                                             of the error.

Comment: It's difficult to get the problem by a screenshot. I think it is a caused by not properly formatted html. When you do slices in Photoshop make them as regular grid, 3x3, 9x9, or just more simple rows, etc, no complex schemas, then assign the links to the interested area in slices property then export to jpg+html. Don't erase white/empty parts since they may work as spacers. If you do it correctly it will work good.